# Pop up displaying on page load and then disappearing after I certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following pop up and I was wondering if there was any way I can get this pop up to appear on page load? Then if there is anyway I can get it to close on it's own without having to be clicked on after a certain amount of time has expired?

```
<div class="dashboard_welcome_help">
    <a class="admin_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Here</a>
    <div class="admin_help_popup light_admin">
        <a class="close_admin_popup" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
        <div id="indexpopupTitleWrap">
            <div id="indexpopupTitle">Have Questions?</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contactMessageStatus"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="white_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('.admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.close_admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the setTimeout function like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
}, 2000);
```

The first parameter is the function to execute, the second parameter is the number of milliseconds to wait before executing it.

Comment: I tried this by itself by replacing my jQuuery and like this and neither worked... `setTimeout(function(){
    $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
 }, 2000);
 $('.admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.close_admin_popup').on('click',function(){
        $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
     });`

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `delay` function like so

```
$(".myPopup").delay( 5000 ).fadeIn("slow");
```

The `delay` function takes a value of milliseconds you would like to have before the actions following the `delay` call are executed

Answer (score 1):

You use javascript setTimeout

```
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var index = getParameterByName("queryString"); // example your url : http://xxx.aspx?queryString=Index


        // Check
        if (index == "Index") {
            // On Load Show
            $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");

            // Set time Out 5 second
            setTimeout(function () { $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow"); }, 5000);
        }

        $('.admin_popup').on('click', function () {
            $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
        });

        $('.close_admin_popup').on('click', function () {
            $(".light_admin,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Awesome! Do you know if there is anyway to make this pop up only appear from a certain destination? Like say I came from the index page, then that would be the only instance it showed up?

Comment: You can use querystring to identify the page need to show and which page not to show... Updated the code